# How to secure a created directory in django so that only django app can access it

Tags: django, file-permissions, directory-permissions

I've created a directory in Django 'mydir' and have few files in it.
How to secure these files so that only django can access it and no one else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done by the following:

```
os.chmod('mydir', 0o400)
```